# jquery-ui dialog being displayed with no content (see update 3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

In my spring project, I have this dashboard page, where each click in a link open the destination page in a separate popup window (created with jquery-ui dialog):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li> <c:url value="/Usuario/listagem" var="usuario"/> <a class="popup" data-action="${usuario}/1/10/1" data-target="popup" href="#">Usu&aacute;rios</a></li>
        <li> <c:url value="/logout" var="logoutUrl"/> <a href="${logoutUrl}">Sair do sistema</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>

<div id="popup"></div>
```

the code to do that it's the following:

```
$( ".dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      closeOnEscape: true,
      closeText: "fechar",
      show: {
        effect: "fadeIn",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "fadeOut",
        duration: 1000
      },
      close: function( event, ui ) {
          $(this).remove();
      }
});
function add_dialog(container_div) {
    var id_dialog_div = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
    var dialog_div = $('<div id="dialog-'+id_dialog_div+'" class="dialog" title="Basic dialog"> <p> <span id="text'+id_dialog_div+'"></span> </p> </div>');
    $(container_div).append(dialog_div);
    return id_dialog_div;
}

function open_dialog(url, dialog_div) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url
    }).done(function(data){
        var id_dialog_div = add_dialog(dialog_div);
        var dialog_box = $('#dialog-'+id_dialog_div);

        var $temp  = $('<div/>', {html:data});

        $( dialog_box ).dialog( { title: $temp.find('title').text() } );
        $( dialog_box ).find('#text'+id_dialog_div).html( $temp.remove('head').html() );
        $( dialog_box ).dialog( { height: 480 } );
        $( dialog_box ).dialog( { width: 640 } );
        $( dialog_box ).dialog( "open" );
    });
}
$(document).on('click', '.popup', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var action = $(this).data('action');
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    var div = $("#"+target);
    open_dialog(action, div);
});
```

the view which should be opened in the popup it's that:

```
<jsp:include page="../../common/listagem.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="name" value="Usuario"/>
    <jsp:param name="elements" value="login,first_name,last_name,email"/>
</jsp:include>
```

and the jsp common/listagem.jsp it's that:

```
<%@ include file="../include/header.jsp" %>

<c:url value="/${param.name}/cadastra" var="cadastra"/>
<c:url value="/${param.name}/altera" var="altera"/>
<c:url value="/${param.name}/remove" var="remove"/>

<input type="hidden" name="pagina" value="${pagina}">
<input type="hidden" name="items" value="${items}">
<input type="hidden" name="ordem" value="${ordem}">

<sec:authorize access="hasPermission(#user, 'altera_${param.name}')">
<p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Cadastrar novo ${param.name} </button>
</p>
</sec:authorize>

<table border="2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <c:forEach var="item" items="${param.elements}" varStatus="index">
                <th class="col" data-property="<c:out value="${item}"/>"> <c:out value="${item}"/> </th>
            </c:forEach>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="content">
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr class="comando">
            <sec:authorize access="hasPermission(#user, 'altera_${param.name}')">
                <td data-nome="altera" data-action="${altera}"></td>
            </sec:authorize>
            <sec:authorize access="hasPermission(#user, 'remove_${param.name}')">
                <td data-nome="remove" data-action="${altera}"></td>
            </sec:authorize>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<c:url value="/${param.name}/listagem.json" var="listagem"/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_content("${listagem}", $('table'));
});
</script>

<%@ include file="../include/footer.jsp" %>
```

My problem is that when I click in the close button, the windows isn't closed immediately, but it's shrunked, remaining only the titlebar. if I click again in the close button, then it close. Also, no title is displayed in the window, but a second (and smallest) titlebar is displayed on the screen with the correct title, and that one I only get to close after the second click in the first close button.

This is what happening:

[image]

Anyone knows what's happening here and how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

In the code above, the line:

```
$( dialog_box ).find('#text').html( $temp.remove('head').html() );
```

should remove from the jsp page the `<head>` tag and its content and append the `<body>` content inside the element `<span>` in this `<div>`:

```
    <div id="dialog" class="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
        <p> <span id="text"> </span> </p>
    </div>
```

But when I run the application, and look the html code in the browser dev tool, all the content from the jsp page is added to the `<div>`, `<head>` included.

**UPDATE 2**

I try remove the function add_dialog, and change the `<div>` to this:

```
<div id="popup">
    <div id="dialog" class="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
        <p> <span id="text"> </span> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the function open_dialog to this:

```
function open_dialog(url, dialog_div) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url
    }).done(function(data){
        //var id_dialog_div = add_dialog(dialog_div);
        var dialog_box = $('#dialog');

        var $temp  = $('<div/>', {html:data});

        $( dialog_box ).dialog( { title: $temp.find('title').text() } );
        $( dialog_box ).find('#text').html( $temp.remove('head').html() );
        $( dialog_box ).dialog( "open" );
    });
}
```

But this work partially: when I open the dialog in the first time, it's displayeh correctly, but after I close and reopen it, the issue happens again.

**UPDATE 3**

I solve the problem with the shunkring / duplication with this code:

```
$( "#popup" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      closeOnEscape: true,
      closeText: "fechar",
      show: {
        effect: "fadeIn",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "fadeOut",
        duration: 1000
      }
});

function open(url, target) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url
    }).done(function( data ) {
        var $temp  = $('<div/>', {html:data});
        var conteudo = $temp.remove('head').html();

        target.empty();
        target.find('#text').html(conteudo);

        $("#popup").dialog('open');
    });
}

$(document).on('click', 'a.link', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var action = $(this).attr('href');
    var target = $('#dialog');
    open(action, target);
});

$(document).on('click', 'button.btn-link', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var action = $(this).data('href');
    var target = $('#dialog');
    open(action, target);
});
```

But now, my dialog is opened without content. Anyone knows what is wrong now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure about all your javascript and i will be not going there but depending on version of jQueryUI your code uses

```
close: function( event, ui ) {
          $(this).remove();
      }
```

throws an error, check the console output in your browser, in my code i have dialog applied to #page_preview

```
$("#page_preview").dialog('remove');
```

Error: no such method 'remove' for dialog widget instance

but as soon as i use

```
$("#page_preview").dialog('close');
```

it works

my entrire code looks like this

```
$("#page_preview").dialog({
        title: "Page Preview",
        dialogClass: "no-close",
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: true,
        modal: true,
        width: 1100,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "OK",
                click: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }]
    });
```

i believe that doing what you are doing in that close: section you are actually removing the element that dialog is applied to, but the dialog structure remains, thats why it seems like it has shrunk

hope it helps

**FINAL EDIT:**

take a look in here, it is slightly different but works, sorry that will be the best i can do for u goo.gl/GLqIYO

Comment: I try remove the code `$(this).remove();` completely, but: 1) still it's displayed the same message in the console; 2)the same issue is happening (a second titlebar is displayed, when i close the main windows, it shrunk instead close). ps.: I don't have a button in my dialog.

Comment: have you tried removing the section completely not just the $().remove() bit, what are your console errors?

Comment: or better, removing your script just to see if dialog on its own works, then you know the issue is with those scripts rather than your dialog declaration

Comment: Yes, I remove all the section where the `$().remove()` bit lies, but the problem persist.

Comment: try the other suggestion of using dialog on its own without the rest of the script to isolate the problem, choose different selectors too just in case, also are you sure your script is not cached

Comment: OK, I update the question to add the description of other things I have tried without success to solve the problem.

Comment: the dialog class is added by jqueryUI dont force it in there, I'm not sure without using all your code what is the issue

Comment: Ok, then I solve the problem of shrunking / duplication, but now the dialog is opened without content. My current code is https://github.com/klebermo/blog.cms/blob/master/src/main/webapp/resources/extra/js/page_link.js

Comment: take a look in here, it is slightly different but works, sorry that will be the best i can do for u http://goo.gl/GLqIYO